# Theading.Timer to call a method every x number of seconds

Tags: c#

I'm playing with thread timers in my application. My code appears to work fine, but the timer doesn't repeat. It will run once, and then stop/hang. I'm using the following code:

```
new System.Threading.Timer(scrape, null, (this.timeout * 1000), System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

`this.timeout` is set to an `int`, for example `5` (5 minutes).

I've checked the docs, and I can't really see any issues. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The timer can be garbage collected if you're not holding reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending parameters wrong.

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(scrape, null, 0, (this.timeout * 1000));
```

last parameter specifies interval.

Also 5*1000 milliseconds is 5 seconds not 5 minutes. if you want 5 minutes then you have to multiply 5 by 60000.

```
this.timeout * 60000
```

Comment: Sorry, I was meant to put seconds, not minutes. Appologies.